# What happens if the limit of 4 billion files was exceeded in an ext4 partition?

Tags: linux, ext4

What happens if the limit of 4 billion files was exceeded in an ext4 partition, with a transfer of 5 billion files for example?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Presumably, you'll be seeing some flavor of "No space left on device" error:

```
# truncate -s 100M foobar.img
# mkfs.ext4 foobar.img
Creating filesystem with 102400 1k blocks and 25688 inodes
---> number of inodes determined at mkfs time ^^^^^
# mount -o loop foobar.img loop/
# touch loop/{1..25688}
touch: cannot touch 'loop/25678': No space left on device
touch: cannot touch 'loop/25679': No space left on device
touch: cannot touch 'loop/25680': No space left on device
```

And in practice you hit this limit a lot sooner than "4 billion files". Check your filesystems with both `df -h` and `df -i` to find out how much space there is left.

```
# df -h loop/
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/loop0       93M  2.1M   84M   3% /dev/shm/loop
# df -i loop/
Filesystem     Inodes IUsed IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/loop0      25688 25688     0  100% /dev/shm/loop
```

In this example, if your files are not 4K size on the average, you run out of inode-space much sooner than storage-space. It's possible to specify another ratio (`mke2fs -N number-of-inodes` or `-i bytes-per-inode` or `-T usage-type` as defined in `/etc/mke2fs.conf`).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, sometime i'm worried, i have over 400 millions files in my main partition (RAID 50), i have many git repository, it was for security if that were to happen

Comment: @ensuperpc: If many of the files aren't regularly used - just there for backup purposes - you might consider putting each project in its own tar file.  That reduces the number of files considerably, and also the space occupied if you use a compression option.

Comment: @jamesqf If you haven't already, try running `git repack` in each git repository to combine all of the separate objects into a pack file.

Comment: @immibis: Same principle, I think, but tar works with every kind of file, not just those within git.

Comment: +1 Since you are just using `touch`, no fancy `echo`, you also show an important point and an often-made misconception: It is possible to fill up a disk with empty files.

Comment: @jamesqf `git repack` doesn't loose any functionality, it is still functionally the same git repo, `tar` makes it unreadable for many programs expecting a project or a git repository

Comment: @Ferrybig: Which would be advantageous if the git repository is being used, even infrequently.  If it's just kept for archival/backup purposes, not so much.  And again, probably not much use for collections of files that aren't git repositories.

Comment: @frostschutz hi, I couuldn't reach your website, I have sent you an e-mail seeking [non-financial] teaching aid from `...438@gmail.com`. I hope you received it.

Answer (score 52):

Once the limit is reached, subsequent attempts to create files will fail with [`ENOSPC`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/creat.2.html#ERRORS), indicating that the target file system has no room for new files.

In the scenario you describe, this will typically result in the transfer aborting once the limit is reached.